# File changes are not reflecting after deployment through Envoyer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, laravel-forge, envoyer.io

I am using Envoyer, and when I deployed my project to a live server using Envoyer, the changes did not occur. But when I restart the PHP server from Forge, it worked. Is there any command I used in the hook that auto-restart the PHP server? I am using an AWS server. Any help would be highly appreciated.